# Tidying / Formating Salesforce Formulas

Tags: formatting, salesforce, atom-editor, pretty-print, sfdc

I am looking for a way to Tidy/Format Salesforce formulas. I know that there is a chrome extension that let's you do that, but it only works in the Edit mode. However when you are in the read-only mode, it displays the Formula as a long text without any Formatting, or Indentation.

Is there Atom plug-in that will allow me to Format / Tidy Salesforce Formulas?

Answer (score 0):

Found two atom packages that will tidy/pretty/format Salesforce formulas:

- https://atom.io/packages/auto-indent
- https://atom.io/packages/bracket-colorizer

Combined, these two packages will provide Salesforce Formula Pretty for Atom